# How to make a function wait returning until a ClientProxy subscribe is done, using nestjs microservices

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, rxjs, nestjs

I have this function which calls another microservice function and I want to return the tags after all elements are added in the subscribe.

This is done in nestjs using microservices.

As it is right now this just returns the empty array, but I want it to return it with the elements.

Does anyone know a fix? thansk

```
private microservicesOptions: ClientOptions = {
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
            host: host,
            port: 3006
        }
    }

    private filterProxy: ClientProxy;

    constructor() {
        this.filterProxy = ClientProxyFactory.create(this.microservicesOptions);
    }

 async getAllTags() {
        let tags = []
        this.postMicroserviceProxy.send<any>("get_posts", "").subscribe(response => {
            response.forEach(element => {
                element.tags.forEach(tag => {
                    tags.push(tag)
                })
            });
        });
        return tags;
    }
```

Comment: What's `this.postMicroserviceProxy`? (specifically, what exactly does `.send()` return?)

Comment: @Tomalak thanks for the answer, i have updated the post, send() returns Observable<any>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an `async` method. `async` only makes sense when you also use `await`, and `await` is not necessary here.

Just return a regular promise:

```
getAllTags() {
    return this.postMicroserviceProxy
        .send<any>("get_posts", "")
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.flatMap(element => element.tags));
}
```

Because it returns a promise, you can still `await` this function, though:

```
async test() {
    const tags = await foo.getAllTags();
}
```

Comment: thanks this works, even though toPromise is deprecated

Comment: @user10468090 I'm not an rxjs pro, feel free use the non-deprecated alternative. The idea counts.